# How can I use texture properties texture in material properties?

Tags: texturing, properties

I want to put the stripe texture on my shoe's vamp, and I find that the wood texture in texture properties is correspond to the texture I want. How can I use the texture in texture properties to material properties?
[image]

Comment: In the same way like current one ? It depends on your current node tree that we don't know.

Comment: You can't use a texture that comes from the Texture panel in your material from what I know but what you show looks like the Texture > Wave Texture

Comment: Blender's Texture system is legacy, and doesn't marry directly witrh shader node trees. In this case, as @moonboots says, that's a _Wave_ texture node ('Diagonal') .. but you can rotate/map that as you wish.